# Implementing a neural network: low accuracy

Tags: neural-network

I'm training my neural network implementation on the [MONK's problems data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/MONK's+Problems). I read that it can be possible to achieve almost a 0 loss with the hyper-parameters I'm using [(chapter 9)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=AF30F83FB7897C5C48A35CE2C3B015CD?doi=10.1.1.45.2363&rep=rep1&type=pdf). These are my results on training set after 90 epochs, they aren't good as you can see:

```
Training error after 0 iterations: 0.26427015361
Training error after 20 iterations: 0.231331617693
Training error after 40 iterations: 0.216396390383
Training error after 60 iterations: 0.198107908553
Training error after 80 iterations: 0.166181613583
TrErr: 0.155389641876
```

And here is the code of my neural network. I think the code is quite simple and readable for a expert, tell me if you need any clarification.

```
# paramaters
etas = [0.1]
hidden_dim = 2
alpha = 0.5
reg_lambda = 0.0

input_dim = 17
output_dim = 1

# read and parse MONK data
def parse_data(text):
    with open(text) as f:
        content = f.readlines()    
    t = np.zeros((len(content), output_dim))
    X = np.zeros((len(content), input_dim))
    for i,val in enumerate(content):
        s = val.split(" ")
        t[i] = float(s[1])
        for idx in xrange(17):
            X[i][idx] = 0.0
        j = -1
        # |0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|13|14|15|16
        # |a1|a1|a1|a2|a2|a2|a3|a3|a4|a4|a4|a5|a5|a5|a5|a6|a6
        X[i][int(s[2])+j] = 1.0 # a1
        j = 2
        X[i][int(s[3])+j] = 1.0 # a2
        j = 5
        X[i][int(s[4])+j] = 1.0 # a3
        j = 7
        X[i][int(s[5])+j] = 1.0 # a4
        j = 10
        X[i][int(s[6])+j] = 1.0 # a5
        j = 14
        X[idx][int(s[7])+j] = 1.0 # a6

    return (X, t)

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

# initialize weights
W0 = np.random.uniform(-0.7,0.7,size=(input_dim,hidden_dim))
W1 = np.random.uniform(-0.7,0.7,size=(hidden_dim,output_dim))
b0 = np.zeros((1, hidden_dim))
b1 = np.zeros((1, output_dim))
dW0 = 0
dW1 = 0

for j in xrange(90):
    # forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0,W0) + b0)
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,W1) + b1)

    # back propagation
    l2_error = t - l2
    l2_delta = l2_error*sigmoid_output_to_derivative(l2) 

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(W1.T)
    l1_delta = l1_error*sigmoid_output_to_derivative(l1)

    if (j% 20) == 0:
        print "Training error after", j, "iterations:",np.mean(np.square(l2_error))

    dW1 = eta*(l1.T.dot(l2_delta) + reg_lambda*W1) + alpha*dW1
    dW0 = eta*(l0.T.dot(l1_delta) + reg_lambda*W0) + alpha*dW0
    db1 = eta*(np.sum(l2_delta, axis=0))
    db0 = eta*(np.sum(l1_delta, axis=0))

    W1 += dW1
    W0 += dW0
    b1 += db1
    b0 += db0
```

Comment: How do you compute the derivative?

Comment: @hh32: ops, I forgot that part. I updated the code with sigmoid and derivative function. ;)

Comment: Could you check this line: 'X[idx][int(s[7])+j] = 1.0 # a6'. I think idx has to be replaced with i.

Comment: Run my code again. You will be pleased. Your implementation was correct, except your bug in the parser ;).

Comment: @LaurensMeeus: classic! Thank you, now it works very well :D

Comment: @StefanoNardo Things like that happen ;) I gladly welcome you to the neural networks team!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just got a bug @ your parse_data. (see my comment: replace `X[idx][int(s[7])+j] = 1.0 # a6` to `X[i][int(s[7])+j] = 1.0 # a6`).

I altered the parameters. You will see that they have a big influence. I guess this problem is easily stuck on a local minima.

Could you run my code please (Only difference is that it is python 3, but should run on python 2)

This is the link of the data saved in data1.txt:
http://mlearn.ics.uci.edu/databases/monks-problems/monks-2.test

import numpy as np
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

# paramaters
eta = 0.05
hidden_dim = 2
alpha = 0.8
reg_lambda = 0.0
epochs = 100

file = 'data1.txt'

input_dim = 17
output_dim = 1

# read and parse MONK data
def parse_data(text):
    with open(text) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    t = np.zeros((len(content), output_dim))
    X = np.zeros((len(content), input_dim))
    for i,val in enumerate(content):
        s = val.split(" ")
        t[i] = float(s[1])
        # for idx in range(17):
        #   X[i][idx] = 0.0
        j = -1
        # |0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7 |8 |9 |10|11|12|13|14|15|16
        # |a1|a1|a1|a2|a2|a2|a3|a3|a4|a4|a4|a5|a5|a5|a5|a6|a6
        X[i][int(s[2])+j] = 1.0 # a1
        j = 2
        X[i][int(s[3])+j] = 1.0 # a2
        j = 5
        X[i][int(s[4])+j] = 1.0 # a3
        j = 7
        X[i][int(s[5])+j] = 1.0 # a4
        j = 10
        X[i][int(s[6])+j] = 1.0 # a5
        j = 14
        X[i][int(s[7])+j] = 1.0 # a6

    return (X, t)

X, t = parse_data(file)

print(np.sum(t)/len(t))

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

# initialize weights
seed = 1
np.random.seed(seed)
W0 = np.random.normal(0, 1/input_dim, size = (input_dim,hidden_dim))
W1 = np.random.normal(0, 1/hidden_dim, size = (hidden_dim,output_dim))
b0 = np.zeros((1, hidden_dim))
b1 = np.zeros((1, output_dim))
dW0 = 0
dW1 = 0


error_list = []
for j in range(epochs):
    # forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0,W0) + b0)
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,W1) + b1)

    # back propagation
    l2_error = l2 - t
    l2_delta = l2_error*sigmoid_output_to_derivative(l2)

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(W1.T)
    l1_delta = l1_error*sigmoid_output_to_derivative(l1)

    error = np.mean(np.square(l2_error))
    error_list.append(error)
    if (j% 20) == 0:
        print("Training error after", j, "iterations:",error)

    dW1 = -eta * (l1.T.dot(l2_delta) + reg_lambda * W1) + alpha * dW1
    dW0 = -eta * (l0.T.dot(l1_delta) + reg_lambda * W0) + alpha * dW0
    db1 = -eta*(np.sum(l2_delta, axis=0))
    db0 = -eta*(np.sum(l1_delta, axis=0))

    W1 += dW1
    W0 += dW0
    b1 += db1
    b0 += db0

plt.plot(error_list)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm using **monks-2** data set not monks-1 (it's easier to train). And I'd like to achieve 100% accuracy after 90 epochs both in **training** and test set, like in the paper I linked in the original post. That's my "oracle". I have to do in this way to know that my implementation is good.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd import the sigmoid function from a python lib, e.g. `sklearn` as they compute it probably numerically more stable than we would.

And another thing: backprop calculates the error as $t_i - o_i$, where $t_i$ is the correct label of sample $i$ and $o_i$ is the predicted output  by your net. You compute it as $o_i - t_i$, so change

```
l2_error = l2 - t
```

to

```
l2_error = t - l2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1. sigmoid function has been already applied to l2. 
`l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1,W1) + b1)`

2. If I reverse the order of the difference the training error diverges. Even if I apply the absolute.

Comment: Yes, that could help. Try that at see what happens. Also, where can i fand the data set? The site you linked seems to be online

Comment: Can't seem to access the data set. But have you tried lowering the learning rate (eta), also it is advantagious to initialize your weights with:
`W0 = (2*np.random.random((input_dim,hidden_dim)) - 1)/input_dim`. It is slightly a better when everything is dived by the input dimension. And the error you wrote is correct ;).

Comment: @hh32: data set is online again. However, I updated the code with better weight initialization and I fixed the error calculation. Now it converges but still not well as I would. Also I added the code to parse the data, if you want to play with it.

Comment: What error rate would you like? And your alpha is still a value to play with.
Btw, I altered your code back to your original error: l2 - t and let dW1 scale with -eta instead of +eta.

Comment: @LaurensMeeus: I'd like MSE under 0.02 with those fixed hyper-parameters. However, I'm going to try a neural network framework and check the results.